# What might cause a ZMQ router socket to block?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

What are common causes for a **`ROUTER`** socket to block on a **`.send()`** to a **`DEALER`** socket in `ZMQ`?

I use Python, but suspect that the answer would be the same regardless of language.

Comment: Post some code if you're hoping for some specific help with what might be happening for you.

Answer (score 1):

**`ZeroMQ`** uses a concept of High-Water-Mark(s).

Earlier versions had just one, a **`HWM`**

Recent versions started to have a pair of **`SNDHWM`** + **`RCVHWM`** ( ref. version-log for details ) with some additional nitty-gritties for guessing the common memory-footprint of each local-side of each `.bind()`/`.connect()`-relation setup allocated by the local `Context()`(s)

Once the process approaches "near" a watermarked level, you may start having issues and/or dropped messages -- check the ZeroMQ documented scenarios for details.

If you opt to post your MCVE-code, there may be more to say on the subject of your particular situation.

Comment: Is high-water-mark the only situation under which a router might block?  Both my router and dealer are newly created.

Comment: Is your MCVE-code near to be posted? There may be more to say on the subject of your particular situation. After your community experience here, at StackOverflow, you must have noted already, that posts that adhere to the **commonly accepted StackOverflow Netiquette** principles get very fast and very experienced answers and typically also many additional pieces of shared know-how.